# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred and few different issues with toString first

Tags: c#

I have been working on this all day and can't figure out why I can't pull this to print of the main class, keeps throwing an error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred

I've tried a few things now and nothing. It works to pull my list from on another class, but I can replicate it. Sorry about code been adjusting a lot

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MpaintV2.Customer
{
    public class Trade
    {
        public String TradeName { get; set; }
        public String TradeAddress { get; set; }
        public String TradePhone { get; set; }
        public Double PaintCoverage { get; set; }
        public String TradeNames { get; set; }

        public string RecCal
        {
            get { return RecCal; }
            set { RecCal = RecCal; }
        }

        public string DataTrade
        {
            get
            {
                List<string> FileData = Utilities.Helper.get_file_data();

                for (int counter = 0; counter < FileData.Count; counter++)
                {   
                    String[] SplitRecord = FileData[counter].Split(',');

                    if (SplitRecord[0].Equals("Trade"))
                    {
                        TradeName = SplitRecord[1];
                        TradeAddress = SplitRecord[2];
                        TradePhone = SplitRecord[3];
                        PaintCoverage = (double.Parse(SplitRecord[4]) / 10.00);
                        // Console.WriteLine(" " + TradeName + " " + TradeAddress + " " + TradePhone + " " + PaintCoverage + "Paints");
                        //List<String> TradeFiles = new List<string>();
                        //TradeNames = String.Join(TradeName, TradeFiles[500]);
                    }
                }

                //TradeFiles = TradeName.Insert.TradeFiles;
                RecCal = TradeNames + TradeAddress + TradePhone + PaintCoverage + "otherthings";
                return RecCal;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at your property RecCal. What **exactly** do its getter and setter? Also, what exactly is the reason for overriding ToString() like you did?

Comment: `RecCal = RecCal` just, no, no, no, CaffeinLevelInsufficientException ;-)

Comment: The getter for `RecCal` is infinitely recursive, change it to `public string RecCal { get; set; }`.

Comment: You are fine with just using an auto-property for your `RecCal`, in fact that would probably be enough to make your code work. It's a bit unusual to see a getter containing a full method as your `DataTrade` member. One would normally use a method to retrieve this output. The question marked as a duplicate should be a good read for you, but if this happens, first try to make sense of it. If you would debug `RecCal` you would see that when you hit the getter, it will recall itself. It's even a bit worse with the setter, where you assign it with the member itself. A setter would have a `value`

Comment: Technically not only is the getter infinitely recursive, but the setter is infinitely recursive too. Or rather would be if it would not right from the start get stuck in an infinite getter recursion. Technicalities... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set RecCal to just `{ get; set; }` as suggested or add a [backing field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field) and change the right hand side of the setter to `value` (keyword). This will let you modify the value during get/set

```
private string _recCal;
public string RecCal
{
    get { return _recCal; }
    set { _recCal = value; }
}
```